# How clear textinput after out of screen in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I try to clear a text in textinput but I have a problem with access to texinput properties. I would like to clear text (entry.text) after when I release button Acceppt and leave the InputScreen. I found get_screen() to set attribute but I don't now how use it with kivy-language

```
ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
        name: "main"
        manager: screen_manager
        numberSet1: input_screen.number1
        numberSet2: input_screen.number2
        numberSet3: input_screen.number3
    InputScreen:
        id: input_screen
        name: "input"
        manager: screen_manager
        textIdToReturn: main_screen.textName

<InputScreen>:

    NawiButton:
        tempNumber: key_board.entryText
        pos: root.width - 100 - 0.25 * root.width, 10
        text: "Acceppt"
        on_release: root.saveValue(root.textIdToReturn, self.tempNumber)
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: .3, 1, .4, .85

    KeyBoardGridLayout:
        id: key_board
        name: "KeyBoard"

<KeyBoardGridLayout>:
    rows: 5
    padding: [100, 10, 100, 100]
    spacing: 3
    entryText: entry.text

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 45
            multiline: False
            on_text: root.update_padding(args[0])
            padding_x: self.width/2


    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 3
        KeyBoardButton:
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text = root.addText(entry.text, self.text)
        KeyBoardButton:
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text = root.addText(entry.text, self.text)
        KeyBoardButton:
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text = root.addText(entry.text, self.text)
```

MainScreen class, but I think is not important:

```
<MainScreen>:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 50
            padding: [300, 50, 300, 50]

            Button:
                text: root.numberSet1
                id: textNum1
                name: textNum1
                font_size: 45
                on_release:
                    root.touch("textNum1")
```

Comment: Please share your MainScreen.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the kv file, use either `on_leave` or `on_pre_leave` event at `InputScreen:` to clear the text (entry.text).

[Screen Manage » API » Events](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#api)

> **Events:**
>
> ```
> on_pre_leave: ()
> ```
>
> Event fired when the screen is about to be
>   removed: the leaving animation is started.
>
> ```
> on_leave: ()
> ```
>
> Event fired when the screen is removed: the
>   leaving animation is finished.

## Snippets

```
ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
        name: "main"
        manager: screen_manager
        numberSet1: input_screen.number1
        numberSet2: input_screen.number2
        numberSet3: input_screen.number3
    InputScreen:
        id: input_screen
        name: "input"
        manager: screen_manager
        textIdToReturn: main_screen.textName

        on_leave:
            root.ids.input_screen.key_board.ids.entry.text = ''
...

<InputScreen>:
    key_board: key_board
```

## Note

### kv file - ObjectProperty and ids

```
key_board: key_board
```

Indicates that an *ObjectProperty* called *key_board* is pointing (hooked up) to the *KeyBoardGridLayout*'s id, *key_board*.

```
entry
```

It is an *id* and a weakref to TextInput widget.

```
entry.text
```

It is referencing the value of *TextInput*'s *text*.

```
entryText: entry.text
```

*entryText* is a property of KeyBoardGridLayout. If the widget doesn’t have a property with the given name, an ObjectProperty will be automatically created and added to the widget. *entryText* is assigned the value of *entry.text*

Comment: Thank you, but I get bug: `NameError: name 'key_board' is not defined`. I tried to refer by id and name too and get the same error

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Updated the post with `root.ids.input_screen.key_board.entryText`

Comment: ok, but I don't understand 2 things. First: `key_board: key_board` and second: entryText points to entry.text, but there are 2 separate variables, so when a clear entryText I suppose I don't clear entry.text in KeyBoardGridLayout.BoxLayout. And this is my problem. How get access to text in TextInput in BoxLayout in KeyBoardGridLayout in InputScreen

Comment: Both `entryText` and `entry.text` are referencing the *TextInput's text* in *KeyBoardGridLayout.BoxLayout* inside InputScreen. Please refer to updated post with detail explanation.

Comment: When I add `on_leave: root.ids.input_screen.key_board.entryText = ''` and `key_board: key_board`, bugs aren't, but the text value is not cleared

Comment: Since your code is minimal, it is difficult for me to trouble shoot the problem. Can you share your complete code in Google ShareDrive or send me an email with complete code?

Comment: I sent on email. Thank you.

Comment: I have just checked your kv file. It is not clearing the TextInput's text because you have `on_pre_enter` in InputScreen. Please replace `on_pre_enter` with `on_pre_leave`.

Comment: Add `root.ids.input_screen.key_board.ids.entry.text` to `on_pre_leave`  because there are two variables having the same value.